# How do I avoid conflicts between haxe Type class and C# Type class?

Tags: namespaces, haxe

I am developing Haxe code that I convert in C# and insert into a Unity project.

The conversion works fine and I am able to use the generated class when I import it alone in Unity.
To make it work, I have to bring in Unity the whole generated `src` folder, including the `Type.cs` file.

However, when I import the "Post Processing Stack" (a basic Unity extension) I get errors due to name Conflicts. The `Type` class is also a basic C# class and It is used by the Post Processing scripts.
The `haxe-Type` takes priority and breaks the compilation:

```
Assets/PostProcessing/Runtime/PostProcessingBehaviour.cs(406,30): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Type,System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<UnityEngine.Rendering.CameraEvent,UnityEngine.Rendering.CommandBuffer>>.Add(Type, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<UnityEngine.Rendering.CameraEvent,UnityEngine.Rendering.CommandBuffer>)' has some invalid arguments

Assets/PostProcessing/Runtime/PostProcessingBehaviour.cs(406,34): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `System.Type' expression to type `Type'
```

I don't know if it is possible to solve this issue by playing around with C#/Unity/Mono search paths.

I as wondering wether it is more appropriate to (optionally) wrap all haxe top-level classes into the `haxe` namespace, or a special `haxe-default`namespace, or prefix them for example to `class HType`.
Name conflicts for this basic types are likely to emerge in many other contexts, not only in Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in the Haxe documentation for C#:
https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/HaxeManual/wiki/Haxe-C%23

> -D no-root generate package-less haxe types in the haxe.root namespace to avoid conflicts with other types in the root namespace

This way, all the classes that were at global level will be generated under namespace `haxe.root`.

Comment: You should also [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).